# Have my <li> display on the same row and other line of <li> on different row

Tags: html, css

How do I put phone number and fax number after Tel: and Fax:?
I tried with `display=in-block` and also reduced the width. But it keeps being on the same place. I want tel: xxxxx and fax: xxxxx to be on different row. not all in different row as it is now. So only 2 row.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/yk072g7q/

Comment: It is already on different rows. Do you mean column?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yk072g7q/3/ don't over-complicate your code, it makes it harder to maintain in the future

Comment: Tel: 000000 should be on first row and Fax: 00000 should be on the second row. I added <li> class for each of them to make Tel and 000 display in different column, and Fax and 000 also.

Comment: Yes, like that. But the numbers should have their own <li class> because they will have to start at the same line. How there starting line are not equal.

Comment: I had the code like yours before. Then I added &nbsp; to make the space equal. But that did not work out. Thats why I have different li class. Like an example table of this site: http://www.kriesi.at/support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.telefon {
    margin: 0px !important; 
    width: 23px;
}

#ett {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width: 220px;
}

.fax {
    display: list-item;
    margin: 0px !important; 
    width: 23px;
}

.nummer {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px !important; 
    width: 100px;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ett">
    <li class="telefon">Tel:</li>
    <li class="nummer">03-3212-8787</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="telefon">Fax:</li>
    <li class="nummer">03-3212-8786</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this decision will suit you. Good luck.

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 5px;
}

ul#ett {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width:140px;    
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.telefon{
    width: 23px;
}

.nummer{
    padding:0 5px;    
}
```

```html
<ul id="ett"><li class="telefon">Tel:</li>
<li class="nummer">03-3212-8787</li></ul>

<ul><li class="telefon">Fax:</li>
<li class="nummer">03-3212-8786</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to do!